# Multiple Input Form States With Nested Data Model React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

New to React JS - I have a form that needs to be mapped to an object.

```
const [client, setClient] = useState({
  name: "",
  code: "",
  address: {
    street: "",
    neighbourhood: "",
    city: "",
  },
  contact: {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    number: "",
  },
});
```

I'd like to use the above approach as this object may grow in the future, and having multiple; `useState("");` will be a nightmare to handle.

I currently use:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const name = e.target.name;
  const value = e.target.value;
  setClient((prev) => {
    return { ...prev, [name]: value };
  });
};
```

in other forms to populate data, using the name and value attribute on the input field, however, this approach only works for a flat object structure. Is there a "better" way to do this with nested data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can go on this approach

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const name = e.target.name;
  const value = e.target.value;

  setClient((prev) => {
    if (name.includes('.')) {
      // Handle nested properties
      const [parent, child] = name.split('.');
      return {
        ...prev,
        [parent]: {
          ...prev[parent],
          [child]: value
        }
      };
    } else {
      // Handle top-level properties
      return { ...prev, [name]: value };
    }
  });
};
```

or for better I recommend you to use [react-hook-forms](https://react-hook-form.com//).